# How to implement connections to Redis Database in Java applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, connection

I am using Redis Database in my Java application (using Spring Boot).

To connect, get, put and delete my json from Redis Cluster I am using [Lettuce open source library](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core).

I have a RedisManager class that handlers connection to database and a RedisCache to effectively execute the commands of get, put and del.

**RedisManager.java:**

```
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisURI;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.ClusterClientOptions;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.api.StatefulRedisClusterConnection;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.resource.ClientResources;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.resource.DefaultClientResources;

public class RedisManager{
    private StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String> connection;
    private boolean clusterMode 

    public RedisManager {
        this.clusterMode = true;

        connect(clusterMode);
    }

    private void connectToCluster(){

        /**
        * It simply gets my endpoint as a string
        */
        String endpoint = PROPERTIES.getProperty(CLUSTER_ENDPOINT);

        ClientResources res = DefaultClientResources.builder()
                .ioThreadPoolSize(3)
                .computationThreadPoolSize(3)
                .build();

        clusterClient = RedisClusterClient.create(res, RedisURI.create(endpoint, 6379));

        try {
            connection = clusterClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**RedisCache:**

```
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandTimeoutException;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisException;
import com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.api.sync.RedisAdvancedClusterCommands;

public class RedisCache {
    private RedisManager redisManager;

    public RedisCache() {
        this.redisManager = new RedisManager();
    }

    public String getAttribute(String hash, String key) {
        String attribute = null;
        try {
            if (redisManager.isClusterMode()) {
                RedisAdvancedClusterCommands<String, String> syncCommands = redisManager.getConnection().sync();
                attribute = syncCommands.hget(hash, key);

            } else {
                attribute = redisManager.getRedis().hget(hash, key);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        redisManager.getConnection().close();
    }
        return attribute;
}
```

How I effectively use these classes:

```
RedisCache cacheService = new RedisCache();
String fund = null;
String hash = "myHash"
String key = "myKey"

try{
    fund = cacheService.getAttribute(hash, key);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, IT WORKS FOR A SMALL NUMBER OF REQUESTS, but, when I stress my API, I receive this error:

```
2017-06-22 16:16:47.804  WARN 5 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.l.r.c.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh  : Cannot connect to RedisURI [host='myHostHere', port=6379]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:58) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:77) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.resource.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.createEventLoopGroup(DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:140) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.resource.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.getOrCreate(DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:114) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.resource.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.allocate(DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider.java:63) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.AbstractRedisClient.getEventLoopGroup(AbstractRedisClient.java:205) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.AbstractRedisClient.channelType(AbstractRedisClient.java:189) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectStateful0(RedisClusterClient.java:703) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectStateful(RedisClusterClient.java:644) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectToNode(RedisClusterClient.java:492) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient$NodeConnectionFactoryImpl.connectToNode(RedisClusterClient.java:998) ~[lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.getConnections(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:204) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:67) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:776) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:752) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectClusterImpl(RedisClusterClient.java:514) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:357) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:334) [lettuce-4.3.2.Final.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.commons.cache.service.redis.impl.RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.connectToCluster(RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.java:153) [bwp-commons-cache-3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.commons.cache.service.redis.impl.RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.connect(RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.java:117) [bwp-commons-cache-3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.commons.cache.service.redis.impl.RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.<init>(RedisManagerCacheServiceImpl.java:48) [bwp-commons-cache-3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.commons.cache.service.redis.impl.RedisCacheImpl.<init>(RedisCacheImpl.java:25) [bwp-commons-cache-3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.commons.cache.service.impl.CacheServiceImpl.<init>(CacheServiceImpl.java:12) [bwp-commons-cache-3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.investment.charts.loading.service.impl.InvestmentChartsLoadingServiceImpl.getFundFromCache(InvestmentChartsLoadingServiceImpl.java:49) [classes!/:3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.btg.pactual.investment.charts.loading.service.impl.InvestmentChartsLoadingServiceImpl.getFund(InvestmentChartsLoadingServiceImpl.java:156) [classes!/:3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor116.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.getFund(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at com.btg.pactual.investment.charts.loading.controller.InvestmentChartsLoadingController.getFund(InvestmentChartsLoadingController.java:50) [classes!/:3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:157) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:149) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:127) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:36) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        ... 107 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:69) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:155) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
        ... 111 common frames omitted
```

I believe it is about how I am calling the connections, can you help me?

Comment: Duplicate of something from https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=java.io.IOException%3a%20Too%20many%20open%20files, in particular https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952635/debugging-the-too-many-files-open-issue is a good candidate

Comment: Generically, it is a good candidate really. I found the solution implementing the RedisManager.java as a Singleton (static)with only ONE connection. Every time I need to get something from Redis, I just get the instance of RedisManager and execute the method (I will post above the solution). Thanks!